# SpringSource: loading properties PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Tool Suite Version: 3.0.0.RELEASE

I want to load my own .properties files to use in my application, so I tried using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Here is my servlet-context.xml code:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="jp.co.rns" />

    <mvc:interceptors>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </beans:bean>
</mvc:interceptors>

    <beans:bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:static" />
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="jp"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="interceptors">
        <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"> 
    <beans:property name="location">
     <beans:value>application.properties</beans:value> 
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders">
    <beans:value>true</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

application.properties:

```
order=2
companyName=Unknown
```

Project structure:

```
src
|
 ---main
|  |
|   ---java
|  |
|   ---resources
|  |
|   ---webapp
|      |
|       ---application.properties
|      |
|       ---resources
|      |   |
|      |    ---application.properties    
|      |
|       ---WEB-INF
|          |
|           ---application.properties 
|          |
|           ---web.xml
|          |
|           ---classes (empty)
|          |
|           ---spring
|          |   |
|          |    ---application.properties
|          |   |
|          |    ---root-context.xml
|          |   |
|          |    ---appServlet
|          |       |
|          |        ---servlet-context.xml
|          |       |
|          |        ---application.properties
|          |
|           ---views (...)
|
 ---test
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I checked, application.properties IS in /WEB-INF/ directory.

But when I start to start server, it gives me an error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application.properties]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your Spring Bean Config file? is it located at WEB-INF? are you loading it from classpath?

Comment: servlet-context.xml is in /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/ directory

Comment: here is web.xml: `<servlet>
  <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by creating new application.properties file in /src/main/resources  Source Folder and copying the content from the old one. Also, I had to change location value to classpath:application.properties
I have a question: will this resource file be compiled into jar? Will I be able to change it without recompiling?
If no, please share some other ways to load external properties.

Answer (score 1):

From [spring-context-3.0.xsd](http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd)

> The location of the properties file to resolve placeholders against,
>   as a Spring resource location: a URL, a "classpath:" pseudo URL, or a
>   relative file path. Multiple locations may be specified, separated by
>   commas. If neither location nor properties-ref is specified,
>   placeholders will be resolved against system properties.

You are not specifying a location that could be resolvable `/WEB-INF/application.properties` is not a url, pseudo URL (like "file:" or "classpath") or a relative file path. I recommend the classpath approach.

---

Comment: Thank you. If I want "relative file path", how should I specify it? Relative to what? And if I use classpath, how should my location property look like in this case?

Comment: It is relative to the Spring Configuration file, suppose that you have a file named applicationContext.xml in WEB-INF, then if you specify a location="application.properties" then Spring will look in WEB-INF/application.properties. In case of a classpath resource then you can put your file inside a jar or the WEB-INF/classes folder, It will resolve in classpath (where the java classes are loaded from).

Comment: Forgot, in a web app, the classpath is also in WEB-INF/lib but must be inside a jar. If you are using maven you can put the file in /src /main/resources and maven will put the file in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: mael, I have web.xml file in /WEB-INF/, but <beans:value>application.properties</beans:value> doesn't work either. And I don't want this file to be compiled into jar, I want to change configuration without recompiling

Comment: A web.xml file? That is the application Deployment Descriptor. That is not a Spring Configuration file...

Comment: Is it pom.xml? or root-context.xml?

Comment: A xml file. If you configured the ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml the default path where spring looks for those files is in /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml... You should really take a look at the spring doc.

Comment: pom.xml is the maven project object model file. probably it is the root-context.xml

Comment: I looked into web.xml, there was <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>, so I think it's root-context.xml, but copying application.properties into /WEB-INF/spring/ doesn't help

Comment: i have <beans:value>application.properties</beans:value> now

Comment: No, the same org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/application.properties]

Comment: Oh, sorry i just have read your post again, you have a DispatcherServlet configured and will look at configs in /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml. You should put your application.properties in /WEB-INF/appServlet/ and modify the servlet-context.xml with the propertyConfigurer. But I do not know why it is not working with your root-context.xml

Comment: bean propertyConfigurer is defined in servlet-context.xml, and I have put application.properties into /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/, but it doesn't help. In fact, I have put the file everywhere I could think of.

Comment: oh well, post your Spring configs files and paths then... I dunno whats wrong this time.